# pkgdown::build_article() fails with large chunk sizes using sf and leaflet, no errors reported when setting quiet=FALSE

Tags: r-markdown, r-sf, r-leaflet, tmap, htmlwidgets

- `pkgdown::build_articles()` fails with large chunk sizes
- `rmarkdown::render()` works fine
- article fails to render any code or text beyond the failed chunk
- no errors are reported with `build_article(quiet=FALSE)`

[image]

- reproducible example below
- `sf` object and plotted with tmap fails at ~9300000 bytes
- not package specific, reproducible with `leaflet` / `htmlwidget` objects as well as `tmap`

Run with:

- `pkgdown::build_article(... quiet=FALSE)` - **fails**
- `rmarkdown::render(...)` - **success**

````
    
    ---
    title: "sf multi-map"
    output: html_document
    ---
  


    ### runs fine with 1000 rows (1260632 bytes)
    
    ```{r}
    library(sf)
    library(tmap)
    
    
    nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
    merged <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(nc), 10))
    
    object.size(merged)
    nrow(merged)
    
    tmap_mode("view") +
      tm_shape(merged) +
      tm_fill(col="NAME", lwd = 0.2) 

  
    ```

    ## no map with 7500 rows (9331032 bytes)

     ```{r, error = TRUE}

    library(sf)
    library(tmap)
    
    
    nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
    merged <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(nc), 90))
    
    object.size(merged)
    nrow(merged)
    
    tmap_mode("view") +
       tm_shape(merged) +
       tm_fill(col="NAME", lwd = 0.2)

 
    ```


    ## no map with 7500 rows with leaflet (9331032 bytes)


    ```{r, error = TRUE}

    library(sf)
    library(tmap)

    nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
    merged <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(nc), 90))
    
    object.size(merged)
    nrow(merged)
    
    tmp <- tmap_mode("view") +
       tm_shape(merged) +
       tm_fill(col="NAME", lwd = 0.2)
    
    tmp2 <- tmap_leaflet(tmp)
    
    object.size(tmp2)
 
    tmp2

    ```
````